# How to detect which Malware has affected my system

Tags: windows-7, malware-removal

My system is showing advertisements of all sorts popping everywhere and I cant use my system properly. Someone suggested it is a malware issue but what are my options how to detect which malware and how to cure it.

Comment: You need to weigh up whether you're going to waste time "fixing" the problem (which may, ultimately, never be achieved), or cut your losses, backup your system and and restore it to a known "clean" state... i.e. a "Factory restore".

Comment: Obviously, Run an anti-malware software...

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you perform an offline scan using something like [Kaspersky Rescue-disk](http://www.kaspersky.com/virus-scanner), which you can burn to a CD/DVD or put on a thumb-drive to boot from (see the linked site for creation details). Once this has been booted you should update the virus signatures database and run a full scan, after which you can remove any identified threats.

On booting Windows again, it would be advisable to disconnect the network entirely until you have subsequently checked through the scheduled tasks (`Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Task Scheduler`) for suspicious looking items, as well as the `Start Menu > Programs > Startup` folder for suspicious looking items, and finally checking through running processes for anything suspicious using the Task Manager (`right click taskbar > Task Manager`).

Finally it is advisable that you check through your installed programs (`Control Panel > Programs and Features`) to remove any suspicious or undesirable software, and check your browser(s) for unwanted plug-ins/extensions.

Once you are happy that you have removed the threat(s) with the above steps as a guideline, you can re-connect the network and resume use as normal.